# How to display table with borders using python CGI script that is displayed in php page

Tags: python, php, html, cgi

I am trying to display results in a table format (with borders)  in a cgi script written in python.
How to display table boarders within python code.

```
  check_list = elements.getvalue('check_list[]')
mydata=db.get_data(check_list)
print("_____________________________________")

print("<table><th>",check_list[0],"</th> <th>",check_list[1],"</th>")
 i = 0 #here
for data in mydata:
    print("<tr><td>",data[0],"</td> <td>",data[1],"</td></tr>")
     i += 1 #here
     if i == 2:#here
         break#here 
print("</table>")
```

the checklist elements represent columns names from a sqlite table. and based on the selected columns the data will be shown.
This code result is just showing two records result with no borders in a php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need CSS styling to define the visuals of your table. Here is a quick introduction to it: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Also, your code tries to do alternating colors for rows, which is nice. CSS supports this, look at this article: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html
This is the part you should look at:

```
tr:nth-children
```

Comment: It it really helped, please consider marking it as answer. It would increase both my number of porints AND my self-esteem. Seriously :)

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's done .

```
 print("<style> table {font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}td, th {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #F5FFFA;}</style><table>")
for c in check_list:
    print("<th>",c,"</th>")

for data in mydata:
    print("<tr>")
    for d in data:
        print("<td>",d,"</td> ")
    print("</tr>")
     
print("</table>")
```